# Add a Submenu from Another Submenu in a Custom Theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, customization

Good day everyone! I would like some help from you since I'm just a beginner in WordPress. I would like to add a submenu under another submenu like this:

- International

  - China Independent

    - Group Tours
    - DPRK Add-ons
    - Classic Chin
    - YPT Exclusive
    - Ticket Services'

I don't have a problem adding them under 'China Independent' when I go to 'Appearance>Menu', however, they don't show up[maybe because it is indeed a custom theme] and I want them to be seen as drop down list on hover since China Independent is another different page. How can I achieve this?

You can see this image: [image]

Or the link: http://www.developerspace.co.vu/

All your help will be greatly appreciated!

> Note: I've also asked it on [wordpress stackexchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) but I have no luck so maybe post my question in here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use javaScript in order to make that, use [this plugin](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/)

Comment: Sorry to ask you more of this despite the fact that you gave the perfect match for what I need. But, how do I integrate it? I'm definitely a noob in WordPress. And, can I add it even if I'm just one of the admins? I have no files of the site in my local.

Comment: That's a problem, you need the files, and some knowledge in javascript, wordpress and php. Sorry

Comment: Yep, just as I thought. Sadly, I'm not the one who developed it. I'm more of a CodeIgniter person than in WordPress. But, thanks for giving me this!